# Google MAP V2 custom info bubble

Tags: google-maps, mapstraction

is there any possibilities that we can add a custom info bubble like the one found in this website? http://app.bg. The website uses v3. However, I need to have a custom info bubble, I am using mapstraction and it is using the v2 api instead of v3.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean v2 of Mapstraction or Google Maps?

If you're using Mapstraction then the same code should work in whatever version of Google Maps you're using.

The Mapstraction method you're looking for is Marker.setInfoDiv - documentation for Mapstraction v2 is [here](http://mapstraction.com/mxn/build/latest/docs/symbols/mxn.Marker.html#setInfoDiv).